# UserPrincipal.SetPassword throws 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I have a Web API that runs in an IIS application pool with elevated service account. This service account has privileges to set or change user passwords within specific OUs in Active Directory.

The API service account is able to set user passwords in OU1 but is **not able to set user passwords in OU2**. Change password works ok in both OUs.

Screenshot for service account permissions on OU2

[image: service account permissions on OU in AD]

Same piece of code is used to set the password regardless of OU.

```
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adContext, username);
userPrincipal.SetPassword("somepassword");
userPrincipal.Save();
```

The exception thrown is

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: On a computer in the "good" OU, and then again on a computer in the problematic OU, run the following command, and compare the differences with a Text Editor that can highlight differences and share any differences found here:  *gpresult.exe /H results.txt*

Comment: @T-Heron sorry for any confusion. The permission I'm looking for is setting password on users within a specific OU. Nothing to do with computers in that OU.

Comment: Are you running this from a computer that is joined to the same domain?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes